# Server Side Event - PHP echo after Event not wanted

Tags: events, echo, addeventlistener, sendmessage

In my project I try to send a PHP Script message to the client, this also works perfectly:

JS

```
    //EVENTLISTENER - MESSAGES
let event_messages = new EventSource('overlays/artikel_einstellen/php/artikel_einstellen.php');
event_messages.addEventListener("messages", function(message) {
    $("#modal_message").append(message.data);
    if (message.data == ''){event_messages.close();}
    console.log(message.data);
}, false);
```

PHP (data: is written with a div - by display: none)
Think thats an uggly way to do that.

```
 echo "<div class='notvisible'>\n\n"; `<-- div container to display:none echos from PHP`
    echo "event: messages\n";
    echo "data: - Daten Komplimentierung abgeschlossen &#10004;<br/>" . "\n\n";
    echo "event: progress_bar\n";
    echo "data: 20" . "\n\n";
    echo "</div>\n\n";
    echo str_pad('', 60 * 1024);
    flush();sleep (1);
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDN3B.jpg)

As u can see, 
But after end of PHP Script, the echo's fires again (what its normal doing)
Is there a way to prevent this?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Was my fault,

was a Fetch response

```
//FETCH
const MyForm = document.getElementById('form_artikel_einstellen');
const formData = new FormData(MyForm);

fetch('overlays/artikel_einstellen/funktion/comp_doctrine_tmp_insert.php',{

    method: 'post',
    body: formData,

}).then(function(response){
    return response.text();

    //return response.json();
}).then(function (text){

    $(".modal_small div.modal-close").show();
    //**$(".modal_small div.modal div.modal_content").append(text);** //<<-- 
    return console.log(text);

}).catch(function(error){
    console.error(error);
})
```